# How to set default values to build a ggplot in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, ggplotly

I've been trying to make my first shiny app using data from the World Happiness report. I wanted to make 2 tabs:

1. Plot using reactive values
2. Table using reactive values

I almost succeeded except for.. when I run the code there's first an Evaluation error, and it disappears after I click on my action button. 
I guess I need some kind of default values to use for the plot and the table.

Is there also a way to avoid duplicating the code for the tabs? Can they share same reactive values? I tried it, but the table updated only when I clicked on the button on the 1st tab, but not on the second. I would be grateful if you suggest the better way to handle it.

Here's the code:

```
`ui <- fluidPage(
       titlePanel(tags$h3("Happiness")), 
       tabsetPanel(
         tabPanel("Plot", "tab1", 
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("factor1", "Choose a value:", choices = c("GDPpc", "Family","Life.Expectancy","Freedom", "Generosity", "Trust"), selected = "Family"), 
               sliderInput(inputId = "happiness1", label = "Choose level of happiness", 
                         min = 0, max = 8, value = 7, step = 0.1), 
               actionButton("button1", "Update")
             ),
             mainPanel(
             # tags$img(height = , width = )
             plotlyOutput("plot1")
             )
           )
           ),
         tabPanel("Table", "tab2", 
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("factor2", "Choose a value:", choices = c("GDPpc", "Family","Life.Expectancy", 
                                                                   "Freedom", "Generosity", "Trust"), selected = "Family"), 
               sliderInput(inputId = "happiness2", label = "Choose level of happiness", 
                         min = 0, max = 8, value = 7, step = 0.1), 
               actionButton("button2", "Update")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tableOutput("table1")
               )
             )
             )
        )
        )`
```

> So you see, my UI is pretty heavy for such a simple app..

```
`server <- function(input, output) {
inputFactor1 <- eventReactive(input$button1, {
  inputFactor1 <-  input$factor1
  })

inputHappiness1 <- eventReactive(input$button1, {
  inputHappiness1 <- input$happiness1
  })

df1 <- reactive({
report %>%
  filter(Happiness.Score >= inputHappiness1()) %>%
  dplyr:: select( "Country", "Continent", "Happiness.Score", inputFactor1(), "GDPpc")
})

observe({
output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
  p <- ggplot(df1(), aes(x = df1()[,4], y = Happiness.Score))
  p <- p + geom_point(size = 2, aes(text = paste("Country:", df1()[,1]), color = Continent,  alpha = 0.85)) + 
    labs(title = "How happy is the country?", x = names(df1())[4], y = "Happiness Score") + 
    theme_light(base_size = 12) + ylim(2,8) 
  ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text", "y"))
})
})

inputFactor2 <- eventReactive(input$button2, {
  inputFactor2 <-  input$factor2
  })

inputHappiness2 <- eventReactive(input$button2, {
  inputHappiness2 <- input$happiness2
  })

df2 <- reactive({
report %>%
  filter(Happiness.Score >= inputHappiness2()) %>%
  dplyr:: select( "Country", "Continent", "Happiness.Score", inputFactor2(), "GDPpc")
 })

output$table1 <- renderTable({
head(df2())
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
```

Here's a [link to the app](https://aliyaadav.shinyapps.io/Source/)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issues lie (lay) when you use `eventReactive` twice, and observer will fire on change in any one. What we can do is the following:

1. Get rid of the `observe` altogether, you dont need it as this is the one that causes the errors as the values initially are `null`, if you want to handle the error then its best you use with `req()` function or `try-catch`
2. Get rid of the the reactives for the inputs, they aren't really necessary as you already can use the `input`
3. Wrap the `df1` and `df2` in `eventReactive` around the button click

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML('<script> document.title = "Happiness"; </script>'),
  titlePanel(tags$h3("Happiness")), 
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", "tab1", 
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("factor1", "Choose a value:", choices = c("GDPpc", "Family","Life.Expectancy","Freedom", "Generosity", "Trust"), selected = "Family"), 
                 sliderInput(inputId = "happiness1", label = "Choose level of happiness", 
                             min = 0, max = 8, value = 7, step = 0.1), 
                 actionButton("button1", "Update")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotlyOutput("plot1")
               )
             )
    ),
    tabPanel("Table", "tab2", 
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("factor2", "Choose a value:", choices = c("GDPpc", "Family","Life.Expectancy", 
                                                                       "Freedom", "Generosity", "Trust"), selected = "Family"), 
                 sliderInput(inputId = "happiness2", label = "Choose level of happiness", 
                             min = 0, max = 8, value = 7, step = 0.1), 
                 actionButton("button2", "Update")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput("table1")
               )
             )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df1 <- eventReactive(input$button1,{
    report %>%
      filter(Happiness.Score >= input$happiness1) %>%
      dplyr:: select( "Country", "Continent", "Happiness.Score", input$factor1, "GDPpc")
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    req(df1())
    p <- ggplot(df1(), aes(x = df1()[,4], y = Happiness.Score))
    p <- p + geom_point(size = 2, aes(text = paste("Country:", df1()[,1]), color = Continent,  alpha = 0.85)) + 
      labs(title = "How happy is the country?", x = names(df1())[4], y = "Happiness Score") + 
      theme_light(base_size = 12) + ylim(2,8) 
    ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text", "y"))
  })

  df2 <- eventReactive(input$button2,{
    report %>%
      filter(Happiness.Score >= input$happiness2) %>%
      dplyr:: select( "Country", "Continent", "Happiness.Score", input$factor2, "GDPpc")
  })

  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    req(df2())
    head(df2())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the error's disappeared but the output is still shown only after clicking the button. Is there a way to set default input values for  `df` so that there's an initial plot shown before activating the button?